# Can't get real current usage and available RAM in PHP using SNMP

Tags: php, ubuntu, snmp, ram, net-snmp

Im planning to fetch RAM usage on server,i tried SNMP in PHP on my own pc but when i wanna get the percentage usage of RAM,that return is not the real RAM usage compare with *system monitor* on my pc.

i have read this solution below but still i didnt get right value

> (Used – buffers – cached) / Total * 100 = % memory used
>
> So you could get the following (expressed as Perl code):
>
> my $memRealTotalOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0';
>
> my $memRealAvailOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0';
>
> my $memRealBuffersOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0';
>
> my $memRealCachedOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0';
>
> Memory Calculations my $memRealUsed = $memRealTotal - $memRealAvail;
>
> Then you can alert on % RAM used:
>
> my $realPercent = (($memRealUsed - $memRealBuffers - $memRealCached )/
>   $memRealTotal) * 100;

Here is my code and the result:

```
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN);
    $memRealTotalOID = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0");
    $memRealAvailOID = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0");
    $memRealBuffersOID = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public",'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0');
    $memRealCachedOID = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public",'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0');
    $memRealUsed = $memRealTotalOID - $memRealAvailOID;

    $realPercent = (($memRealUsed - $memRealBuffersOID - $memRealCachedOID) / $memRealTotalOID) * 100;
    print_r($realPercent);
```

the current result is = 82.55542380

meanwhile system monitor is showing (89%):
[image]

Did i read wrong solution or wrong calculation?Any help pls

Comment: Debugging step #1 would be to print intermediate results, eg. memRealTotalOID, memRealAvailOID, etc. Also, since we are learning to program, the names of the variables are not correct. Those are not OIDs returned from snmpget, but the values of the MIB objects. The OIDs are .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0, etc.

Comment: @GambitSupport 'Those are not OIDs returned from snmpget, but the values of the MIB objects' ya i know that.Then how i can get the real RAM usage,i have debug one by one results of the RAM,but i still didnt get relation to get real percentage of RAM usage

Comment: If you print the intermediate results, you have an answer to your questions.

Comment: It's not clear what "real RAM usage" actually means. Modern computers are complicated, and there are multiple potential definitions for this value. Even if you settle on a single set of data, there are differing averaging periods used by different tools, and that could easily be all you're seeing. Describe what you _actually_ wish to know.

Comment: I doubt this is really the cause of the problem, but your code has a race condition - obtain all four values in _one go_ rather than making separate requests.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well,in simple ways i wish to know my current RAM usage by using SNMP and compare it with my system monitor,but the SNMP return many kind variables of RAM so i dont know which one is the 'real' RAM usage

Comment: @GambitSupport what is 'intermediate results' means?

Comment: Again, "my current RAM usage" is ill-defined. There is no "real" RAM usage; there are different measurements and different ways of describing them. You have to decide exactly which combination you're after (and, possibly, to compare with System Monitor, find out exactly which combination it uses; again I suspect some running averaging here).

Comment: "intermediate results" means ANYTHING to allow you to diagnose the problem, eg. the values of memRealTotalOID, memRealAvailOID, etc.